# Storing user credential at local storage of android device (Internal memory) which should be hidden from user or unaccessible

Tags: android

I have an registration layout with its java file to store the user's credential locally to its app directory. But i need to store those credentials somewhere user can't access or make any change.
Is there a way to do. If so kindly help.

My .java file.

```
public class screen_25 extends Activity {

EditText searchBox;
EditText searchBox1;
EditText searchBox2;
EditText searchBox3;
EditText searchBox4;
EditText searchBox5;
TextView response;
Button save;
Button read;

private String fileName = "SampleFile2.pdf";
private String filePath = "MyFileStorage";
File myExternalFile;
String myData="";
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_25);

    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save_user);
    response=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);
    searchBox=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);
    searchBox1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox1);
    searchBox2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox2);
    searchBox3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox3);
    searchBox4=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox4);
    searchBox5=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox5);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            try{
                FileOutputStream fos =new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
                fos.write(searchBox.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.write(searchBox1.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.write(searchBox2.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.write(searchBox3.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.write(searchBox4.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.write(searchBox5.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            searchBox .setText("");
            searchBox1.setText("");
            searchBox2.setText("");
            searchBox3.setText("");
            searchBox4.setText("");
            searchBox5.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);
    read.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine;
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            searchBox.setText(myData);
            searchBox1.setText(myData);
            searchBox2.setText(myData);
            searchBox3.setText(myData);
            searchBox4.setText(myData);
            searchBox5.setText(myData);
            response.setText("SampleFile.txt data retrieved from Internal Storage...");
        }
    });

    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        save.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else {
        myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filePath), fileName);
    }


}
private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}}
```

I have created a sample file to save those credentials. i need to store those somewhere safe where user cant access or modify those files.

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for are SharedPreferences.
Here's a tutorial on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned by [@Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7929094/pascal) - you can use shared preferences. I would clarify such topic. I think that using file for such data has some bad sides:

1. So huge actions with data
2. Easy to get it - one the other hand when a user will have root access he will be able to see SP (shared prefereces) data too.

So, as I see you would like to save some string data to apps storage. For writing data you need firstly to define global SP variable:

```
SharedPreferences mSettings;
```

than inside `onCreate()` method assign value:

```
mSettings = getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

After it you can read/write some data. General types are [mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)). So data writing you have to set key-value info into app storage:

```
mSettings = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key_name", "some string data");
editor.apply();
```

and to read written data use such code:

```
String dataString = mSettings.getString("key_name", "default string value");
```

you can get such variables from any screen of your app. So, you can see that such method is lighter that files writing.